How to restrict points on a curve in geometry nodes to a grid on Z axis?
I want to build geometry nodes modifier that would generate castle walls based on a curve. I want these walls to always have same alignment in Z, and to have an outside parameter of "Stair height" that would restrict all walls to be on integer multiples of this height.
Basically I want this curve

To be resampled into something like this

So that I can create walls like this 
With what combination of geometry nodes could I achieve that?

An initial naive approach.
In this approach, the walls are a little tilted, and you control the amount of tilt with the subdivider (I understand the problems this might bring, but it's a first thought)

This is how it looks if the "subdivide mesh" node is set to zero:


This is a bit cleaner than my approach, the "Floored modulo" is really neat! Thanks!
I don't particularly care for extruded mesh, since I'm gonna use instances of object anyway.

What I needed was a maths trick. We can leverage Round function to "snap" Z coordinate to specific points. Since we don't want to be limited by default grid units, we need to first divide the Z coordinate by step size to get the "grid size", then round, and multiply back to get to the original range.
Nodes:

Result:

Possible improvements: Get Z coordinate of first and last point of the curve, and use Map Range node to fix start and end points. As is, the ends can float a bit over the curve end based on step size. Not worth doing for my use case, but something to think about.
